# delete files in a directory which do not match a specific file name without extension

Tags: linux, bash

My directory looks like that:

- test.png
- test2.png
- test.jpg
- test2.jpg
- test.jpeg
- test45.jpeg
- test.gif
- test3.gif

Now I'd like to run a linux command which deletes all files which are not exactly 4 characters *without / ignoring* the extension.

Resulting in the following directory:

- test.png
- test.jpg
- test.jpeg
- test.gif

Any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` to find all files with a format of `????.*` (4 characters plus a period plus a variable number of characters):

```
$ find . -type f -name "????.*"
./test.gif
./test.jpeg
./test.jpg
./test.png
```

Negating this approach (ie, find all files other than those with a format of `????.*`):

```
$ find . -type f ! -name "????.*"
                 ^ ---- negate next option
./test2.jpg
./test2.png
./test3.gif
./test45.jpeg
```

Apply a `-exec/rm`:

```
find . -type f ! -name "????.*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Or pipe the results to `xargs/rm`:

```
find . -type f ! -name "????.*" -print0 | xargs -r -0 rm
```

If you have subdirectories then all of the above will apply the `find/rm` against files in said subdirectories; to limit the `rm` operation to the current/parent directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "????.*" -exec rm {} \;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Why using recursion where OP didn't say anything about?

Comment: See [find's "-exec rm {} \;" vs "-delete"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167823/264812).

Comment: If using a `find` that doesn't support the `-delete` option, a good alternative is to use `find ... -exec rm {} +` (which is POSIX-compatible).

Answer (score 1):

Using `extglob` option:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(?????(.*([^.])))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo rm !(????.*)
```

Remove `echo` to delete for real.